# For a matrix $A\in SL_{n}(\Bbb R)$ is $\nabla^{n} \det(A)$ always $0$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, determinant

Let $\nabla=\frac{d}{da}+\frac{d}{db}...$ denote the sum of the partial derivatives with respect to the matrix indexes. I noticed that $A:2\times2$, $\nabla \det(A)=a+d-c-b$ and that $\nabla^2 \det(A)=1+1-1-1=0$

This also looks to be true for $A:3\times3$ with $\nabla^{3}$. Is this true for all dimensions? If so, what is the reason?

Comment: Could you explain what the $\nabla$ means in this context?

Comment: It is the [gradient](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient) with respect to the matrix indexes $a,b,c,d...$.

Comment: For $A \in \mathbb{R}^{2 \times 2}$, $\det(A) = ad-bc$. Then did you mean $\nabla \cdot \det(A) = (\partial_a+\partial_b+\partial_c+\partial_d)(ad-bc) = d-b-c+a$ ? So what ? The $n+1$-th derivatives of a polynomial of degree $n$ vanish, and for $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\det(A)$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ in the coefficients of $A$, thus $\nabla^{n+1}\det(A) = 0$. Also defining the determinant by induction on $n$, you should get something like $(A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, \nabla^n.\det(A) = 0) \implies (A \in \mathbb{R}^{n+1 \times n+1}, \nabla^{n+1}.\det(A) = 0)$

Comment: @aleden,  I think you did not write what you meant, when you edited your question.  Did you not mean to write something like  "Let $\nabla = \partial/\partial a  + \partial/\partial b + \dots$ denote the sum of the partial derivatives with respect to the matrix entries of a (variable) $n$-by-$n$ matrix."  Please note that $\nabla^n$ is not the sum of $n$-th partials, as you wrote.

Comment: @aleden you still have written "$n$-th partial derivatives" where you just meant "partial derivatives".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\def\sgn{\operatorname{sgn}}$
Let $X$ be the generic $n$-by-$n$ matrix $(x_{ij})$  with the $x_{ij}$ variables.  Let $D = \det X = \sum_\pi \sgn(\pi) \prod_i x_{i \pi(i)}$.

Write $\partial_{ij}$ for the partial with respect to $x_{ij}$, and  $\nabla = \sum_{ij} \partial_{ij}$.   This is not the gradient but a particular directional derivative, as pointed out in the comments by loup blanc.  It appears to be what the OP had in mind.  If it is not what the OP had in mind, I will withdraw this answer.

Then $\nabla^n$ is a sum of all possible products of length $n$  of the partials $\partial_{ij}$ (i.e. mixed partials of length $n$).  But most of these, applied to $D$, are zero because $\partial_{i j} \partial_{k l} D = 0$ if $i = k$ or $j = l$ because in these cases $x_{ij}x_{kl}$ never appears as a factor of any monomial contributing to $D$. Those partials which are non-zero each occur with multiplicity $n!$.  Thus $$\nabla^n  D = n! \sum_\sigma  \prod_i \partial_{i \sigma(i)} D = n! \sum_\sigma \sum_\pi \sgn(\pi) \prod_i \partial_{i \sigma(i)}
\prod_j x_{j \pi(j)}.$$
Let's write out a typical summand for security:
$$
\sgn(\pi)(\partial_{1 \sigma(1)}\cdots \partial_{n \sigma(1n)})(x_{1 \pi(1)} \cdots x_{n \pi(n)}) = \sgn(\pi) \delta(\sigma, \pi).
$$
Hence $\nabla^n D = n! \sum_\pi \sgn(\pi) = 0$.

Comment: Thank you, I could kind of see how it is true visualy and by comparing determinants for different dimensions but I did not know how to prove it for all dimensions.

Comment: Your $\nabla$ is not a gradient; it's the directional derivative of a function along the vector $[1,\cdots,1]^T$ or, also, the dot product of the true gradient and of the vector $[1,\cdots,1]^T$. Where is the interest of this calculation ? At least, change the OP's notation

Comment: Sorry, I never used the word gradient.  I took for $\nabla$ what the OP demonstrated by example that he/she meant, which is scalar valued, not vector valued.   Better ask the OP to change his/her terminology, and to clarify what is meant by the operator $\nabla$.  OK?

Comment: @ loup blanc, please see revised answer which points out your comment.  Thanks.

Comment: OK, I agree. I meant that the OP does not know what is a gradient.

Comment: The OP discovered a phenomenon by example, and didn't know precisely how to communicate it.  But one should encourage, not discourage, the habit of noticing phenomena.